# Insert timestamp into mysql column in shell

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, unix

The following works for me:

```
mysql -u 'root' -h 8.8.8.88 mo -e 'UPDATE `path_last_updated` 
    SET timestamp="2012-01-03 00:00:00"'
```

However, the following does not:

```
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%T"`
mysql -u 'root' -h 8.8.8.88 mo -e 'UPDATE `path_last_updated` 
    SET timestamp=$TIMESTAMP'
```

How would I insert the timestamp from unix into my mysql table?

**Update**:

```
TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %T"`
mysql -u 'root' -h 8.8.8.88 mo -e "UPDATE `path_last_updated` 
    SET timestamp='$TIMESTAMP'"

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET 
timestamp='2013-01-31 15:46:00'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variable interpolation [only works between double quotes ("), not single (')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).  You've also got backticks in there, which in a double-quoted string will be treated as an embedded shell command.

Try:

```
mysql -u 'root' -h 8.8.8.88 mo -e "UPDATE \`path_last_updated\`
    SET timestamp='$TIMESTAMP'"
```

Also, fwiw, you have an extra dash (-) in your format for the date command, between the %d and %T.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The first half is now working for me -- it's executing with the variable. But it doesn't seem to be a valid SQL statement for whatever reason. Please see updated question.

Comment: Seems like you've got it sorted anyway.  I've added a comment on the backticks.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE` to make it easier:

```
ALTER TABLE path_last_updated ADD date_entered timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

And then in shell:

```
mysql -u 'root' -h 8.8.8.88 mo -e "UPDATE path_last_updated SET timestamp=DEFAULT"
```